# CSS flexbox, positioning

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Мaybe this question will sound like a stupid, but i am new to HTML coding.
For example, I want to make a row like this...
[image: screenshot showing a row with text on the left and image on the right]

But so that the right side is outside the container and the left side stays in the container. And make it so that with the screen width on phones, the right side goes to the next line, like here...
[image: screenshot showing row with text on top and image on bottom]

I was able to exit from the container by using absolute positioning, but I need to do it responsive for all devices.

Comment: Have you attempted to create this with `flexbox` if so, where is the code?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Generally, if you're asking a question about code that doesn't work, we need to see an example of the code, in the question. formatted as code.

Answer (score 0):

Using flex without using `@media`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.parent > * {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  min-width: 800px;
}
```

Assuming an HTML code like this:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first">
    <h1>
      Lorem ipsum dolor
    </h1>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    img
  </div>
</div>
```

So:

- Make a [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
- [Wrap](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-wrap/) the flex box tiles.
- Set a minimum width for each tile.

That implies: when the tiles can't shrink, they wrap (moving the second tile to the next line).

Answer (score -1):

It's very easy with Flex. Make a parent div then add two child div. For example-

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.first-child, .second-child{
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child">
    <h1>This is my first headline</h1>
    <p>Paragraph </p>
  </div>
  <div class="second-child">
    <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4580330/pexels-photo-4580330.jpeg" width="100%" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```